# Update table of component in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two components, A and B and also a service. I want to update table of component B every time that a option in component A is selected. The update happens very well in first time, but after that, I have a problem with subscribe, because there many subscribers and the methods are executed again and again. I want to execute only once the methods that are in onInit,because them fetch data from serve for populate that table.

This is component A. Every time that a option is selected the method onChange is executed.

**Template component A**

```
 <select class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
 <option *ngFor="let gradeBloco of gradeBlocoNumParciais"[value]="gradeBloco?.getCodigo()">{{gradeBloco.descricao}}</option>
</select>
```

**Method component A**

```
onChange(gradeBlocoCod) {
 this.turmaDisciplinaService.gradeBlocoNumParciais = 
 this.gradeBlocoNumParciais.find(gradeBloco => gradeBloco.codigo == 
 gradeBlocoCod);
 this.nextSubjectByRoute();
}
```

**Method for execute Subject**

```
nextSubjectByRoute(){ 
  this.turmaDisciplinaService.subjectGradeBlocoNumParciaisNotas.next();
}
```

**Service**

```
export class TurmaDisciplinaService {
   turmaDiscip: TurmaDisciplina;
   gradeBlocoNumParciais: GradeBlocoNumParciais;
   boletim: Boletim;
   turmaDisciplinaAlunos: TurmaDisciplinaAluno[] = [];
   subjectTurmaDisciplina = new Subject<TurmaDisciplina>();
   subjectGradeBlocoNumParciaisNotas = new Subject<GradeBlocoNumParciais>();
}
```

**Template component B**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr class="d-flex">
                  <th class="col-md-1 hard_left numSeq" scope="col">Nº</th>
                  <th class="col-md-6 next_left" scope="col">Nome</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" *ngFor="let avaliacao of avaliacaoService.avaliacoes" scope="col"><modal-edit-avaliacao [avaliacao]="avaliacao" ></modal-edit-avaliacao><!--<a title="Editar Avaliação" class="btn" (click)="hellow()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>{{avaliacao.nome}}--></th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Média</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr class="d-flex" *ngFor="let tda of turmaDisciplinaAlunos;  let j = index;">
                  <td class="col-md-1 hard_left numSeq">{{tda.numSequencia}}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-6 next_left">{{tda.aluno.nome}}</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" *ngFor="let avaliacao of avaliacaoService.avaliacoes; let i = index;"><!-- usado para criar a linha de notas -->
                    <input id="{{'c'+i+'l'+j}}" (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)" type="number" min="0" max="10" [disabled]="inputDisabled" [ngClass]="{'input-notas': true, 'nota':notaInvalid}" [ngModel]="turmaDiscAlunoNotas[j][i]?.nota" (ngModelChange)="turmaDiscAlunoNotas[j][i].nota = $event" (change)="handleChange(turmaDiscAlunoNotas[j][i])">
                </td>
                  <td class="col-md-2" id="col-media">{{turmaDiscAlunoMedia[j]}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Method onInit component B**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.todayDate = this.utilService.getCurrentDate();

        this.turmaDisciplinaService.subjectGradeBlocoNumParciaisNotas.subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.turmaDisciplinaService.gradeBlocoNumParciais = res;
            this.initTurmaDiscAlunos();
            this.initAvaliacoesArray();
        });

}
```

Comment: is this getting executed  console.log(res);?

Comment: yes, for tests..

Comment: Firstly I have 100 requests, it is normal, but after two or more changes in select I have more than 800 requests to server, because every time the next method of subject is executed

Comment: @FranklinPious ???

Comment: I dont get your exact problem..what is your objective..? is the subscribe not getting called or is it something else.?

Comment: @FranklinPious The subscribe is called. The problem is that I have many subscribers, it result in many repetitive http requests.

Comment: does the http requests produce the same result every time and so you want to get it called only once .?

Comment: @FranklinPious yes

Comment: @FranklinPious look that https://imgur.com/a/7bzumj1

Comment: How does these many request get called on a single change .?
are you subscribing it on multiple components.?

Comment: @FranklinPious 100 requests its normal. the problem is when next() method of subject is called. Every time that option changes it s called resulting in many subscribers. Look the first image, it normal. When I change the option, the problem starts.

Comment: Then move the functions which are making the Api calls to outside of the subscribe function.

Comment: @FranklinPious look inside onInit() of component B. There a subscribe that is called when I choose another option.

Comment: @FranklinPious But I need execute them for fetch the new data. Them are executed only when I choose another option in select.

Comment: I still dont undestand what you are trying to achieve..The subscribe is called when an option is chosen and the functions inside subscribe are called and API calls inside those functions happen.

Comment: @FranklinPious exactly

Comment: Look that class of component that has subscribe https://pastebin.com/FJCPjjj5

Comment: Component of the select https://pastebin.com/w2TrrSNZ

Comment: Service https://pastebin.com/7csG89nH

Comment: @FranklinPious If I don't use subjects I can't update table

Comment: @FranklinPious ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution..

Add this variable in component B.

```
public subscribers: any = {};
```

After that implement onDestroy interface in component B add the following code on the method overrided.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   subscribers.name.unsubscribe();
}
```

Finally modify ngOnInit with this code.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.todayDate = this.utilService.getCurrentDate();
  this.subscribers.name = this.turmaDisciplinaService.subjectGradeBlocoNumParciaisNotas.subscribe(res => {
        this.turmaDisciplinaService.gradeBlocoNumParciais = res;
        this.initTurmaDiscAlunos();
        this.initAvaliacoesArray();
    });
   }
```